# Scroll bar inside a div with table

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have a Div in my web page which is scroll-able, in that div I present a table.

The problem is that the div has round corners, but the scroll bar is coming out from the corners.

How can I fix that? I wish to push the scrollbar to the right and show in underneath the div.

```
    #TableDiv{
height: 100%;
width: 97%;
margin: auto;
overflow-y:auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Inside that Div I show a table with a lot of data.

This is how the edge looks like:

[image]

Comment: Share the HTML code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container {
  background-color: #9498b3;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

.container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: green;
}
.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="container">
  some text is here some text is here some text is here some text is here some text is here some text is here some text is here   some text is here some text is here some text is here some text is here some text is here some text is here some text is here   some text is here some text is here some text is here some text is here some text is here some text is here some text is here   some text is here some text is here some text is here some text is here some text is here some text is here some text is here   some text is here some text is here some text is here some text is here some text is here some text is here some text is here
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Try this but notice that custom scroll bars are not supported in Firefox or IE/Edge.

```
#TableDiv::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
}
#TableDiv::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#TableDiv::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: No, that didn't do anything

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirement correctly, is this what you looking for?

```css
.main {
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #666;
  padding: 6px 0px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.TableDiv {
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="TableDiv">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <Td>When the API returns an image. I see more and more Image-Response GET APIs. With this term I mean: the API is called with a GET URL, and the response is a (JPG/PNG/GIF/WEBP/SVG) image, either directly or after a redirect. So the API can be used.
          When the API returns an image. I see more and more Image-Response GET APIs. With this term I mean: the API is called with a GET URL, and the response is a (JPG/PNG/GIF/WEBP/SVG) image, either directly or after a redirect. So the API can be used</Td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, I wish that the scroll bar will be inside the "ticket" and that is won't hide the rounded corners please.

Answer (score 0):

i have here a example. I hope it is how you want it, otherwise say it!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

div.scroll {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  overflow: scroll;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="scroll">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div>

</body>
</html>
```